# What is the difference between "createReadStream" and "Readable" class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone explaint Difference between `createReadStream` and `readable` in node.js? By my observes they are similar, so what is under the hood difference, and when should each be used?

for example

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: AWSConfig.AWSConfig.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: AWSConfig.AWSConfig.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });

    const params = {
      Bucket: AWSConfig.AWSConfig.bucket,
      Key: "somebucketName/1620072325205",
    };
    const file = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    const fileSize = file.ContentLength / (1024 * 1024);

    const read = new Readable({
      read(fileSize) {
        this.push(file.Body);
        this.push(null);
      },
    });

    read.pipe(res);
```

this is similar to

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: AWSConfig.AWSConfig.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: AWSConfig.AWSConfig.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });

    const params = {
      Bucket: AWSConfig.AWSConfig.bucket,
      Key: "somebucketName/1620072325205",
    };
    const file = await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
    file.pipe(res)
```

Comment: `fs.createReadStream()` creates a Readable that is getting its data from a file.  Readable is a generic thing.  It can be hooked to lots of different types of sources of the data.  So, `fs.createReadStream()` creates one hooked to a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a NodeJS, you can create a readable stream in a few ways:

**SOLUTION 1**

You can do it with `fs` module. The function `fs.createReadStream()` allows you to open up a readable stream and all you have to do is pass the path of the file to start streaming in.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const readable_stream = fs.createReadStream('file_path');
```

**SOLUTION 2**

If you don't want to create file, you can create an in-memory stream and do something with it (for example, upload it somewhere). ​You can do this with `stream` module. You can import `Readable` from `stream` module and you can create a readable stream. When creating an object, you can also implement `read()` method which is used to read the data out of the internal buffer. If no data available to be read, `null` is returned. The optional `size` argument specifies a specific number of bytes to read. If the `size` argument is not specified, all of the data contained in the internal buffer will be returned.

```
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;

const readable_stream = new Readable({
  ​read(size) {
   ​// ...
​  }
});
```

**SOLUTION 3**

When you are fetching something over the network, that can be fetched like stream (for example you are fetching a PDF document from some API).

```
const axios = require('axios');

const readable_stream = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: "pdf_resource_url",
  responseType: 'stream'
}).data;
```

**SOLUTION 4**

Third party packages can support creating of streams as a feature. That is a way with `aws-sdk` package from your example.

**SUMMARIZE AND CONCLUSION**

You can create a `readable` stream in a few ways. Since you are already using `aws-sdk` package, I would say that you should go with using their `createReadStream()`, instead of importing `stream` module and creating `readable` stream with it.

Comment: Thank you for your attention perfect explanation

Comment: Welcome. Consider also accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worth to mention is the `Readable.from` method which allows you to create a reable stream by providing an `iteratable` to it (a `String` for example). See the following example:

```
const { Readable } = require("stream");

const readableStream = Readable.from("In-memory data to a readable stream");
```